# InvalidArgumentException : Cannot write to directory | running Laravel

Tags: permissions, sudo, directory, laravel

this may be an easy error but I've been stuck in this one for 3 days now.
I'm not a very experienced coder. It's my first time using Laravel too. I bought this script with a guide (at least something like a guide) that I follow but still get `InvalidArgumentException  : Cannot write to directory "/var/www/blog/storage/app\public\products"`when I run `php artisan db:seed` to populate the page and database with dummy data.

I'm running on 18.04 with LEMP stack and a user in `sudo` and `www-data` groups. What I did was upload the script into `/var/www` via SMTP and unzip and proceeded to run these commands in order (as given by the guide):

```
sudo chown myuser:myuser /var/www/blog
cd /var/www/blog
composer install
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/blog/public
sudo chmod 755 /var/www
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/blog/bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/blog/storage 
php artisan storage:link
sudo mkdir /var/www/blog/storage/public/products
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/blog/storage/public/products
sudo chgrp -R www-data /storage/public/products
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx /storage/public/products
```

And then I proceeded to fill .env with the database info and everything went fine from database configuration to migrating and then the last step is the `db:seed` to check, that where I got stuck. Been reinstalling OS several times, trying some ways I find on google... so here I am.

Comment: Where do the back slashes (\\) come from? They shouldn't occur in a proper Ubuntu path.

Comment: I don't know as well, tbh.

Comment: Well, then do `grep -r "public\\\products" *` in your application root directory. Three backslashes.

Comment: ```storage/logs/laravel.log:[2019-04-15 10:51:36] local.ERROR: Cannot write to directory "/var/www/blog/storage/app\public\products" {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Cannot write to directory \"/var/www/blog/storage/app\\public\\products\"```

```database/seeds/ProductSeeder.php:            $newImage = 'products/'. $faker->image(storage_path('app\public\products'),256,256, null, false);```

it seems it cannot write into it, having an image of a dummy data.

Comment: So there in `/database/seeds/ProductSeeder.php` you have a path with backslashes. Replace these by forward slashes (`/`) and try again.

Comment: Slashes are not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give write permission to www-data group on the products folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/blog/storage/public/products
```

Comment: Still same error ```InvalidArgumentException  : Cannot write to directory "/var/www/blog/storage/app\public\products"```

Answer (score 0):

See the database \ seeds folder, look for the file that is responsible for filling with fake data (ProductSeeder)

find the line $ faker-> image (storage_path ('app \ public \ products') and change the slash in the opposite direction. Like this $ faker-> image (storage_path ('app / public / products')